# How can I change the color of the font in the Title with Xamarin.Forms?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am setting a title like this:

```
 Title = "Card " + index;
```

and then later in my code I increment index and set it once more:

```
 Title = "Card " + index;
```

Is there a way that I can change the color of the title to Gray that will work in both iOS and Android?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Xamarin Forms Way:

You can use the `NavigationPage.BarTextColor` for this. Set this property when you initially create the `NavigationPage`.

iOS Way:

You can also add the following to the your AppDelegate to change the bar text color globally for the iOS side (I usually put them between the `Forms.Init()` and `LoadApplication()` lines:

```
UINavigationBar.Appearance.SetTitleTextAttributes(new UITextAttributes { TextColor = UIColor.White });
```

Android Way:

And then you could do it globally in your Android project by applying the correct theme. See [this link](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/comment/159200/#Comment_159200) for an example or that (look for the **Style action bar tab text and color color selector** part).